# Module not loading in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, npm, aurelia

I'm currently running into a weird issue when trying to load a module with Aurelia. I've successfully loaded the `moment` library for formatting dates, however I am trying to load the `numeral` library exactly the same way with `npm install <module> --save`, but it is trying to find the `numeral` library in the `/dist` directory rather than the module library.

I have two ValueConverters below:

---

Code using `Moment`:

**src/filters/time-format.js**

```
import moment from 'moment';

export class TimeFormatValueConverter {
  toView(value) {
    return moment(value).format('h:mm');
  }
}
```

**src/clock.html**

```
<template>
  <require from="./filters/date-format"></require>
  <require from="./filters/time-format"></require>
  <section class="au-animate">
    <h2 class="clock-font-large">${time | timeFormat}</h2>
  </section>
</template>
```

---

Code trying to use `Numeral`:

**src/filters/temperature-format.js**

```
import numeral from 'numeral';

export class TemperatureFormatValueConverter {
  toView(value) {
    return numeral(value).format('(00)');
  }
}
```

**src/weather.html**

```
<template>
  <require from="./filters/temperature-format"></require>
  <section class="au-animate">
    <h2 class="clock-font-large">${weather.main.temp | temperatureFormat }</h2>
  </section>
</template>
```

---

I am getting the following error when trying to see the page using `numeral`:

```
ERROR [app-router] Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://clock.localhost:9000/dist/numeral.js
    Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://clock.localhost:9000/dist/numeral.js
    Error loading http://clock.localhost:9000/dist/numeral.js as "numeral" from http://clock.localhost:9000/dist/filters/temperature-format.js
```

Why is it trying to look in the `/dist` directory rather than the module library? I know there is some break in the dependency injection, but I'm not sure what to do about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are using SystemJS. So, what you should run is:

`jspm install numeral`

Unless if you are doing something very specific, you don't have to install any packages using NPM when working with SystemJS Skeleton.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Aurelia-cli, simply add the following code to your `aurelia.json` file in the `aurelia_project` folder:

```
                {
                    "name": "numeral",
                    "path": "../node_modules/numeral",
                    "main": "numeral"
                },
```

In Aurelia, you're always required to explicitly list your dependencies.

If you're using the Skeleton installation, see Fabio's answer.

Comment: Given the mention of `/dist', @cchapman is not likely to be using the Aurelia CLI.

Comment: Good catch. Thanks! My answer would only work with the CLI.